# Unable to access Kubernetes UI

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I configured k8s(kubernetes) with 1 master and 2 slaves. I was able to access web UI provided by k8s but after rebooting of M/cs, not able to access UI with the same URL. May be I am missing with some of environment variables or something else, didn't able to figure it out correctly. Did any one know, what I am missing ?
`docker ps` shows that I am running the desired containers. Images are-
`gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.0.1` and `gcr.io/google_containers/pause:2.0`
I followed this [link](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/locally/#running-a-container).

Comment: What URL were you using?

Comment: @ Robert..Sorry for late reply. URL that I am using is-  https://<master-ip>:8080/ui  as given at [this link](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/)

Comment: Can you run `kubectl describe endpoints --namespace kube-system kubernetes-dashboard` and see if it shows any addresses?

Comment: Thanks for the response Robert. Now, I am able to access the UI. Problem is because of old DNS entry of kube-dashboard pod inside the kube-dns pod. So I restarted kube-dashboard pod and kube-dns pod and things are working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigating to `https://<master-ip>:8080/ui` will redirect you to the `kubernetes-dashboard` service in the `kube-system` namespace. When you first set up your cluster this service was working properly but after rebooting the set of endpoints became stale. You can diagnose this issue by running `kubectl describe endpoints --namespace kube-system kubernetes-dashboard` to see the current set of endpoints, and if they are incorrect (or missing), restarting the dashboard pod and/or dns pod will resolve the issue.